# Trying to enable IPv6 results in a "No route to host" error

Tags: networking, ipv6, routing

I'm configuring a dual stack network on a KVM server using static IPv4 and IPv6 addresses furnished by my provider.

I input all addresses, nameservers and gateways as required when installing Ubuntu. After that, I checked the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and noticed that the IPv6 stanza was absent (an `ifconfig` execution confirmed this), so I added the relevant lines. This is the final file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 151.236.18.86
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 151.236.18.0
        broadcast 151.236.18.255
        gateway 151.236.18.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 91.227.204.227 91.227.205.227
        dns-search mydomainname.com
iface eth0 inet6 static
        pre-up modprobe ipv6
        address 2001:b60:1000:151:236:18:86:0
        netmask 112
        gateway 2001:b60:1000::1
        dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
        dns-search mydomainname.com
```

I then restarted networking via `sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop && sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` and noticed that, while IPv4 was working, outbound IPv6 connectivity was not available (I did not check for inbound connectivity yet).

`ifconfig` and `ip -6 addr` show the IPv6 address is recognized:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:b1:27:87  
          inet addr:151.236.18.86  Bcast:151.236.18.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:feb1:2787/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:b60:1000:151:236:18:86:0/112 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16409 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1126656 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:763658 (763.6 KB)

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:b60:1000:151:236:18:86:0/112 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feb1:2787/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On the contrary, no default route exists for the IPv6 stack:

```
$ ip -6 route
2001:b60:1000:151:236:18:86:0/112 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

Trying to add the missing route leads to "No route to host" error:

```
$ sudo ip -6 route add default via 2001:b60:1000::1
RTNETLINK answers: No route to host
```

What could be wrong, and how can I fix the network configuration so that I can get the IPv6 stack working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the network mask length given to me by the provider was incorrect: the right one was `48`. Changing it did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

Inside your virtual machine, run the following:

```
ping6 ff02::2%eth0
```

This `ff02::2` is the IPv6 "all routers" multicast address. The on-link router will respond to the ping with its own address. For example:

```
64 bytes from fe80::56e6:fcff:fef4:66f1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.347 ms
```

You can then add this in as the `gateway` address.

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
        .....
        gateway fe80::56e6:fcff:fef4:66f1
        .....
```

Comment: I did that, three routers responded (no one matched the gateway address my provider gave me); I chose the one with the lowest latency and changed the network configuration. Now name resolution works, but IPv6 connectivity does not (I issued `ping6 -c 3 ipv6.google.com`, the DNS found the address but there was 100% packet loss). Any ideas?

Comment: Three different routers responded? Your provider has an even more bizarre setup than we'd suspected. At this point I can only suggest you try each of them, and see if one of them works. If _none_ of them work, you'll have to contact the provider to ask them to kindly fix their broken network. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your netmask should be 64. With IPv6 every LAN is usually a /64. I guess your provider allows you to use a /112 from that /64, but you should configure a /64 on the interface.

Comment: I reconfigured the IPv6 stack to use a /64 netblock, unfortunately the problem persists with the same symptoms.

Comment: I am sorry, I now see that your host is in 2001:b60:1000:151::/64 and your gateway in 2001:b60:1000:0::/64. CDLAN must have given you the wrong information, or their IPv6 network is messed up and/or deviating from standard practice...

Comment: This weird deviation is, unfortunately, all too common among VPS providers.